# Map variable that has been created azure dev op to terraformer variable.tf

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, terraform

I created the same question in the past but I would like to make it more clear.

In azure devops pipelines library I created a variable called AZ_DEVOPS_CLOUD_CLIENTS, it contains a secret that we generated in an app registration in azure. What I want is to use that variable to my varible.tf file.

So what we have:

My **varible.tf**
how it is

```
  variable "client_secret" {
  

default = "secretpass" ## secret its in plaintext

}
```

How I want to be

```
variable "client_secret" {
type = string


default = "#{AZ_DEVOPS_CLOUD_CLIENTS}"}
```

Is something like that possible to basically map the variable fro mazure dev ops to my tf file so in that way we can avoid plaintext secret on our local repository files?

Note we do not have key vaults or something like that the variable is created directly to azure dev ops and later on we would like to use them for pipelines.